# Running HBaseTestingUtil in non-test code fail with ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert

Tags: java, hbase, hbasetestingutility

We have a non-standard setup where we run our application with an HBaseTestingUtil during our integration tests, but we bring up the mini cluster in non-test code.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-testing-util</artifactId>
    <version>${hbase.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

We recently upgraded from HBase1.x where it worked to HBase2.x which it not stopped working and our service crashes with
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert`

Part of the stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351) ~[?:1.8.0_372]
        at org.apache.hadoop.test.GenericTestUtils.assertExists(GenericTestUtils.java:290) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.test.GenericTestUtils.getTestDir(GenericTestUtils.java:234) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.test.GenericTestUtils.getTestDir(GenericTestUtils.java:243) ~[hadoop-common-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.getBaseDirectory(MiniDFSCluster.java:2915) ~[hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.determineDfsBaseDir(MiniDFSCluster.java:2905) ~[hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.initMiniDFSCluster(MiniDFSCluster.java:847) ~[hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.MiniDFSCluster.<init>(MiniDFSCluster.java:810) ~[hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:671) ~[hbase-server-2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniDFSCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:643) ~[hbase-server-2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1096) ~[hbase-server-2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseTestingUtility.startMiniCluster(HBaseTestingUtility.java:1071) ~[hbase-server-2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297-tests.jar:2.2.3.7.1.6.0-297]
```

The above also provides some info as to the specific versions we use.
I tried adding (no scope, and also tried runtime scope):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>  
</dependency>
```

Didn't work, so I assume the above code uses some test-specific classloader that doesnt contain all the classes from normal dependencies? Though not sure how thats possible.

Also tried the shaded version hoping it might pack junit in there, but didnt work.

Can I get this to work somehow?